# Solving the functional equation $2f(x)-f(1/x)=3x$

Tags: analysis, functions, functional-equations

If $$2f(x)-f(1/x)=3x$$ how would I find $f(x)$?

I have tried various linear and other functions but I do not know how to start this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that 
$$2f(1/x)-f(x)=3/x.$$
Use this and the original equation to solve for $f(x)$.

Comment: can you explain ( or add to answer ) how we can get to this equation

Comment: The given functional equation presumably holds for all $x$ where it makes sense, that is, everywhere except $0$. We can write it as $2f(t)-f(1/t)=3t$. Set $t=1/x$.

Comment: wow, i am really stupid ! :)

Comment: @Cardinal: Domain  is not really of importance. The original equation would not be sensible if there were $x$ in the domain such that $1/x$ is not in the domain.

Comment: yes, i see, thanks

Comment: Thanks so much! That was very helpful

Comment: You are welcome.